# How to fix problem of flicking views using .matchedgeometryeffect with animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

Anybody knows how to fix problem of flicking views using .matchedgeometryeffect with animation

[Flicking views gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCOvN.gif)

In my mind I need to disable opacity transition but I dont know how

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {

@State private var isChanged = false
@Namespace var space

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        if !isChanged {
            Rectangle()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: space)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            
        } else {
            Rectangle()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: space)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation() {
            isChanged.toggle()
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Use scale animation instead of this

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the transition:

```
func transition(_ t: AnyTransition) -> some View
```

like this :

```
ZStack {
        if !isChanged {
            Rectangle()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: space)
                .transition(.scale)  // <--- Define the transition to Scale
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)


        } else {
            Rectangle()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: space)
                .transition(.scale) // <--- Define the transition to Scale
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)

        }
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation() {
            isChanged.toggle()
        }
    }
```

If you only need to scale your view you can also apply:

```
ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "1", in: space)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .scaleEffect(isChanged ? 3 : 1)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation() {
                isChanged.toggle()
            }
        }
```